# How to properly pass a variable from one child element to another in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, flask

I am trying to pass data from a button click event in ToolBarElement.js to GraphElement.js

The backend is using Flask to serve data on `/data` route

It seems to build without errors, but it returns a blank screen if I include the line           `<p>{state.graph_data}</p>` in GraphElement.js

App.js

```
function App() {

  const state = {
    graph_data: 0,
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-body">
        <div className="toolbar-element" style={{ top: "50px", left: "0px" }}>
          <ToolbarElement props={state} />
        </div>
        <div className="graph-element" style={{ top: "50px", right: "0px" }}>
          <GraphElement props={state} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div >
  );
}

export default App;
```

ToolbarElement.js

```
function ToolbarElement(props) {

  const { state } = props;

  const [data, setdata] = useState({
    lst: [],
  });

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    console.log('Button clicked!');
    fetch("/data").then((res) =>
      res.json().then((data) => {
        // Setting a data from api
        setdata({
          lst: data,
        });
      })
    );
    state.graph_data = data.lst[0]; //Getting first data value from List
  };


  return (
    <div style={{ height: '33.33%', backgroundColor: '#F0F0F0' }}>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Click me!</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ToolbarElement;
```

GraphElement.js

```
function GraphElement(props) {

  const { state } = props;  

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '33.33%', backgroundColor: '#E8E8E8' }}>
      <p>{state.graph_data}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default GraphElement;
```

The error I get in console is `olbarElement.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'graph_data')`

Comment: in this case `state` is just a set of variables I would like to share between different elements, it has nothing to do with the useState hook

Comment: essentially what Im trying to do is just pass data by reference as in C++, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
<GraphElement state={state} />
```

Comment: nice catch on the error in passing props.

Answer (score 0):

You're close to the right answer.  You've lifted shared state up into the `App` component.  But you can't just use a regular old object as state in the `App` component.  You need to instead use the `useState` hook in `App` and pass `state` and `setState` down into the child components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Context to avoid prop drilling( passing data from multiple components until it reaches the component that needs it).

Read more at: [avoiding prop drilling](https://blog.logrocket.com/solving-prop-drilling-react-apps/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).